# Maximum value of product of column vectors

Tags: matrices, optimization

Consider $3$ dimensional unit column vectors $\hat{n}=[n_{1},n_{2},n_{3}]$ and $\hat{c}=[c_{1},c_{2},c_{3}]$ and diagonal matrix $T=$Diag$[T_{1},T_{2},T_{3}]$. The problem is that given a particular vector $\hat{c}$ find the maximum value of $\hat{n}^{T}T\hat{c}$ for all possible values $\hat{n}$ where $\hat{n}^{T}$ is the transpose of $\hat{n}$.

Comment: is $T$ fixed? is there any restriction on the elements of $T$?

Comment: yes T is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $$(n_1,n_2,n_3)\begin{pmatrix}T_1 & 0& 0\\ 0& T_2 & 0\\ 0& 0& T_3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\ c_2\\ c_3\end{pmatrix}=T_1c_1n_1+T_2c_2n_2+T_3c_3n_3.$$ So the maximum value is obtained when

$$(n_1,n_2,n_3)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{T_1^2 c_1^2+T_2^2 c_2^2+T_3^2 c_3^2}}(T_1c_1,T_2c_2,T_3c_3).$$

Why? We have that $$(a_1,a_2,a_3)\cdot(b_1,b_2,b_3)=\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2}\cos(\widehat{a,b}).$$ If $b$ is given, when is maximum the product? If we assume $a$ is a unit vector then we achive the maximum when the angle between $a$ and $b$ is zero. That is, when $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2}}(b_1,b_2,b_3).$

Comment: will you elaborate the process a little bit?

Comment: I have added an explanation. Let me note if it helps.

Comment: Yes. I understood as the components of $b$ are fixed this choice is unique.